# Button isn't calling javascript function on click

Tags: function, button, onclick

I made a button in html and used onclick to trigger a javascript function, but it isn't being called.

```
<button type="button" onclick="openNav()"><img src="hamburger.png"></button>
```

```
<script>
    function openNav() {
        document.querySelector('#dropdown').style.display="initial";
    }
</script>
```

I appreciate any help.